# scala.js call external js function

Tags: javascript, salesforce, scala.js

I want to try using `scala.js` on a `SalesForce` project.

SalesForce automatically injects the `Visualforce.remoting.Manager.invokeAction(...)` function to enable querying data and doing `dml`.

How can I call this function from scala.js?

Answer (score 1):

In the crudest sense, you could just invoke it directly from global scope using `js.Dynamic`, something like:

```
js.Dynamic.global.Visualforce.remoting.Manager.invokeAction(...)
```

That works for a one-off, but if you're going to be working more with this Manager, I'd probably recommend creating [a Scala.js facade](http://www.scala-js.org/doc/interoperability/facade-types.html) for the Manager, and assigning the Manager object to that -- it'll probably result in better code in the long run.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to call any exposed javascript method from scala-js using

```
scala.scalajs.js.eval(x: String)
```

Example for calling a [bootbox](http://bootboxjs.com/) modal:

```
 import scala.scalajs.js.annotation.JSExportTopLevel
 import scala.scalajs.js

 @JSExportTopLevel("myCallBack")
 protected def confirmCallback() = // do stuff

 def askAQuestion(): Unit = {
    js.eval("bootbox.confirm(\"Your question goes here.\", function(result) { if (result == true) { myCallBack(); }});")
 }
```

Of course for this to work you have to include the javascript libary in your project.

Since this is a quite messy solution, you might consider writing your own facade.